# How to pass generically scoped suspend lambda to class method in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Want to have a function inside an open class which can accept a suspend lambda and run it.

I know this works when you specify the type explicitly but if possible need it to accept generically scoped lambdas.

```
class ChildClass : SuperClass() {

    // does work :)
    fun launch(block: suspend ChildClass.() -> Unit) =
        coroutineThing { this.block() }

}
```

```
open class SuperClass {

    // doesn't work :(
    fun <T : SuperClass> launch(block: suspend T.() -> Unit) = 
        coroutineThing { this.block() }

}
```

The error I am getting is `Expression 'block' of type 'suspend T.() -> Unit' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found.`

**Edit:**

Looking to eventually call this method from an instance of the ChildClass like this: `ChildClass().launch { doStuff() }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write like this but I don't know how it works :) For me, it looks like Kotlin issue.

```
open class SuperClass {
    fun <T : SuperClass> launch(block: suspend T.() -> Unit) =
        coroutineThing { block.invoke(this as T) }
}
```

but in that case you have to invoke it like this:

```
ChildClass().launch<ChildClass> { println("test") }
```

but you can change it a bit to invoke it like you want:

```
open class SuperClass<T : SuperClass<T>> {
    fun launch(block: suspend T.() -> Unit) =
        coroutineThing { block.invoke(this as T) }
}

class ChildClass : SuperClass<ChildClass>()

//invokation
ChildClass().launch { println("test") }
```

Comment: Thank you! They both work for me, I've opted to use the latter, works better in my use case.

Comment: Yes, the second is the standard (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_quantification#F-bounded_quantification or search for "F-bounded polymorphism").

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
open class SuperClass {


    fun<T: SuperClass> launch(superClass: T, block: suspend T.() -> Unit) {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            superClass.block()
        }
    }

}


open class ChildClass: SuperClass() {
    suspend fun print() {

    }
}


fun test () {
    val a = ChildClass()
    a.apply {
        launch(this) {
            print()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't quite work for me as I need the launch method to be inside the SuperClass. This method will ideally be called from instances of the ChildClass, would prefer not to create an instance of ChildClass just to pass in. End goal would be something like this: `ChildClass().launch { doStuff() }` :)

Comment: @jtsalva I tweaked the solution a little bit, please check now

Comment: Guess this does work but was looking for something cleaner, chosen to use Andrei's answer.